# codeception : Setting the "doctrine" pre-defined service is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported anymore in Symfony 4.0

Tags: php, symfony, testing, doctrine-orm, codeception

My project is a Symfony 3.3.9 project with Doctrine ORM. 
I use codeception 2.3.6 with the module Doctrine2, I follow this article : http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Doctrine2

My config of codeception is :

```
#tests/functional.suite.yml
actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Functional
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost 
        - Symfony 
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony
            cleanup: true
```

When I run the suite of tests with this command

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run functional
```

The tests pass very well with Success, but deprecated messages are thrown :

Setting the "doctrine" pre-defined service is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported anymore in Symfony 4.0

When I remove the configuration of Doctrine2 module from functional.suite.yml

```
#tests/functional.suite.yml
actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Functional
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost 
        - Symfony
```

I have to remove the calls of `$I->grabEntityFromRepository()` in my tests classes, and the deprecated disappear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue on my projects.
The issue is opened on github https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4318

The problem is not into Doctrine2 module of codeception but into Symfony module of codeception.

The method Codeception\Module\Symfony::_getEntityManager() want to persist 3 services doctrine, doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager, doctrine.dbal.backend_connection

```
public function _getEntityManager()
{
    if ($this->kernel === null) {
        $this->fail('Symfony2 platform module is not loaded');
    }
    if (!isset($this->permanentServices[$this->config['em_service']])) {
        // try to persist configured EM
        $this->persistService($this->config['em_service'], true);

        if ($this->_getContainer()->has('doctrine')) {
            $this->persistService('doctrine', true);
        }
        if ($this->_getContainer()->has('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')) {
            $this->persistService('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', true);
        }
        if ($this->_getContainer()->has('doctrine.dbal.backend_connection')) {
            $this->persistService('doctrine.dbal.backend_connection', true);
        }
    }
    return $this->permanentServices[$this->config['em_service']];
}
```

The error is triggered from Codeception\Lib\Connector\Symfony::rebootKernel() :

```
public function rebootKernel()
{
    foreach ($this->persistentServices as $serviceName => $service) {
        $this->container->set($serviceName, $service);
    }  
}
```

You can comment the issue of github, it is not closed right now.

Edit : You can define error_level in you config file and add ~E_USER_DEPRECATED :

```
#tests/functional.suite.yml
actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Functional
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost 
        - Symfony 
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony
            cleanup: true
error_level: "E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED"
```

http://codeception.com/docs/04-FunctionalTests#Error-Reporting

Comment: So, how to remove this deprecated message ?

Comment: You can ask question on github. Try to configure error_level: "E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED"`  into your codeception.yml file

Comment: thx, there is no real solution. Good to know there is an issue on github ;)

Comment: Nobody is working on the issue. Solutions are welcome.